# storing output of a mathematical expression

Tags: unix, awk, sh, sunos

i am new to SunOS unix system. i want to store the uptime and convert it into minutes in a shell script.
below is what i used inside script.

```
hrs=`uptime | awk '{print \$5}' | sed 's/[:,]/ /g' | awk '{print \$1}'`
mins=`uptime | awk '{print \$5}' | sed 's/[:,]/ /g' | awk '{print \$2}'`
uptimesecs=$(($mins*60)))
```

and error what i got in script.

[image]

can anyone help me with the syntax

Comment: awk can parse and calculate alone. you don't need parse it twice. And there is still `x days` you may want to consider.

Comment: What's the value of `uptime`? Maybe it's locale dependent.

Comment: The `$` is already protected from expansion inside the single quotes you used to provide the `awk` script; the backslash is unnecessary and preventing *`awk`* from using it as a field expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You are overquoting the `$`s in the `awk` scripts:

```
hrs=`uptime | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[:,]/ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
mins=`uptime | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[:,]/ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`
```

You're also doing more work than is necessary. Get the uptime *once*:

```
uptime=$(uptime | awk '{print $5}')
```

Then split the value on a `:` using the shell itself.

```
IFS=: read hrs min <<< "$uptime"
```